# Octree implementation

Tags: c++, c, gpu, octree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast, templated, C++ Octree implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963954/fast-templated-c-octree-implementation)

Can anyone suggest some well-tuned implementations out there for the octree on the CPU or the GPU
in C or C++?

Also since Octrees can be represented with and without pointers, can someone please tell me
the possible pros or cons for either technique.

Thank you,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963954/fast-templated-c-octree-implementation

Comment: That depends on your application. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I want it for doing smooth particle hydrodynamics....which is one of many methods to model fluid flow using particles...Since the neighbourhood search for a particular particle is quite compute intensive, i needed this data structure

Comment: too bad this thread has been closed, I wished someone would have commented on the 'pointerless octree' part of your question (not addressed in the so-called duplicate).